# Wrong Result from SQL Server CTE hierarchy

Tags: sql-server-2014, common-table-expression, hierarchical, recursion

i have an application serve multilevel of permissions and roles

i have this HIERARCHY :

---

Country

....Region

........City

............Association

................Center

....................School

........................Class

---

this HIERARCHY i name it "EntityLevels"

```
| ID | Name        | ParentID |
|----|-------------|----------|
| 1  | Country     | Null     |
| 2  | Region      | 1        |
| 3  | City        | 2        |
| 4  | Association | 3        |
| 5  | Center      | 4        |
| 6  | School      | 5        |
| 7  | Class       | 6        |
```

---

i have also a Groups Table which means Jobs

```
| ID | Name               | EntityLevels |
|----|--------------------|--------------|
| 1  | CountryAdmins      | 1            |
| 2  | Region Supervisors | 2            |
```

---

the user table is as following

```
| ID | Name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | User1 |
| 2  | User2 |
```

---

now i have a UserJobs Table or UserGroups

```
| ID | UserID | GroupdID | EntityID |
|----|--------|----------|----------|
| 1  | User1  | 1        | 1        |
| 2  | User2  | 2        | 2        |
| 3  | User3  | 4        | 38       |
```

---

now the problem is how i can get each user and his responsibilites depending on what it's under his level

for eaxmple :

user1 must have all the roles and permissoins to see all users under his level because he is in Group (1) and Group1 it resides on EntityLevel (1) which it's on the Country Level.

i've try to do something like that, but it's not working as Expected it's Only give me the root without any other child under that root

```
;WITH MyCTE AS (
  SELECT T1.ID, UserId, 0 AS TreeLevel, CAST(T1.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath FROM ApplicationUserGroups T1
  inner join EntityLevels el on t1.GroupId = el.Id WHERE EL.ParentID IS NULL
  --where (select ParentID from EntityLevels where id = T1.GroupId and ParentID is Null) Is Null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT T2.ID, T2.UserId, TreeLevel + 1, CAST(TreePath + '.' + CAST(T2.ID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255)) AS TreePath
  FROM ApplicationUserGroups T2
  inner join EntityLevels el on T2.GroupId = el.Id
  INNER JOIN
  MyCTE itms ON itms.ID = EL.ParentID
)
-- Note: The 'replicate' function is not needed. Added it to give a visual of the results.
SELECT ID, Replicate('.', TreeLevel * 4) + UserId 'Name', TreeLevel, TreePath
FROM  MyCTE 
ORDER BY TreePath;
```

---

**Script for Schema And DATA**

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4cb2494ce472f22b7241aa5ef1ccfbbe)*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assocation](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Assocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Center]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Center](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssociationID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Center] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[City]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Class]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Country]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EntityLevel]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EntityLevelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Region]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[School]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CenterID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserJobs]    Script Date: 2017-04-03 6:07:29 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserJobs](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserJobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC,
    [EntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (1, N'KH', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (2, N'mkh_ass', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (1, N'NorthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (2, N'SouthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (1, N'Jeddah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (2, N'MakkahCiry', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (1, N'Class1-Ahmed', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (2, N'Class2-omar', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (3, N'class3_khaled', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (4, N'class4_fahd', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'KSA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UAE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, N'Country', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, N'Region', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, N'City', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, N'Association', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (5, N'Center', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (6, N'School', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (7, N'Class', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (1, N'SA', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (2, N'country admin', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (3, N'region admin', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (4, N'region Supervisor', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (5, N'manager', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (6, N'supervisor', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (7, N'teacher', 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (1, N'Makkah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (2, N'Riyadh', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (1, N'School1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (2, N'School2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (3, N'School3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (1, N'Loai', N'000000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (2, N'User1', N'1111')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (3, N'User2', N'2222')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (4, N'User3', N'3333')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (5, N'User4', N'4444')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (6, N'user5', N'5555')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (7, N'user6', N'6548')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 2)
GO
```

any solution for that ?

(EDIT) : The Expected Result will be :

[image]

**SCRIPT AND DATA VERSION #2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assocation](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CityID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Assocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Center]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Center](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AssociationID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Center] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[City]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Class]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Class] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Country]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[EntityLevel]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntityLevel](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Group]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Group](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EntityLevelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Group] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Region]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Region](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Region] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[School]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CenterID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserJobs]    Script Date: 2017-04-04 3:47:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserJobs](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserJobs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [UserID] ASC,
    [GroupID] ASC,
    [EntityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (1, N'KH', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Assocation] ([ID], [Name], [CityID]) VALUES (2, N'mkh_ass', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (1, N'NorthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Center] ([ID], [Name], [AssociationID]) VALUES (2, N'SouthCenter', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (1, N'Jeddah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[City] ([ID], [Name], [RegionID]) VALUES (2, N'MakkahCiry', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (1, N'Class1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (2, N'Class2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (3, N'class3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Class] ([ID], [Name], [SchoolID]) VALUES (4, N'class4', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'KSA')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Country] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'UAE')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (1, N'Country', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (2, N'Region', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (3, N'City', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (4, N'Association', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (5, N'Center', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (6, N'School', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[EntityLevel] ([ID], [Name], [ParentID]) VALUES (7, N'Class', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (1, N'Country Manager', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (2, N'Region Manager', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (3, N'City Manager', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (4, N'Association Manager', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (5, N'Center Manager', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (6, N'School Manager', 6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Group] ([ID], [Name], [EntityLevelID]) VALUES (7, N'Teacher', 7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (1, N'Makkah', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Region] ([ID], [Name], [CountryID]) VALUES (2, N'Riyadh', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (1, N'School1', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (2, N'School2', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[School] ([ID], [Name], [CenterID]) VALUES (3, N'School3', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (1, N'UserA', N'000000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (2, N'UserB', N'1111')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (3, N'UserC', N'2222')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (4, N'UserD', N'3333')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (5, N'UserE', N'4444')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (6, N'UserF', N'5555')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (7, N'UserG', N'6548')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (8, N'UserH', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (9, N'UserI', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[User] ([ID], [Name], [Mobile]) VALUES (10, N'UserJ', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (8, 8, 2, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (9, 9, 3, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[UserJobs] ([ID], [UserID], [GroupID], [EntityID]) VALUES (10, 10, 4, 2)
GO
```